# Why is this GUID not valid?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, guid

```
AB77085F-C0BB-4C78-B2F2-3H8F6F8D0C28
```

It was generated with the NEWID() Sql server 2008 R2 function

It is not accepted in a uniqueidentifier field

It is not valid for Guid.TryParse() in C #

Comment: `H` is not a valid hex digit. Wherever this came from it was *not* from `NEWID()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because all the values should be hexadecimal. You got a letter `H` inside.

> AB77085F-C0BB-4C78-B2F2-3**H**8F6F8D0C28